# How to use the flag -loadJarClassifier in stanford ner to create your own jar file?

Tags: stanford-nlp

How to create your own jar file containing your own NER model as a default in Stanford NER?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be to add your trained model to a jar file.

Here is a link for adding files to a jar file:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

If you want to make a jar file like `my-custom-models.jar` here is info on creating a jar file:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Then put that jar file in your CLASSPATH.

If you want to load your custom model at start up time, you just need to specify that with the `ner.model` property.

From the command line:

```
-ner.model /path/to/my_model-1.ser.gz,/path/to/my_model-2.ser.gz
```

Java API:

```
props.setProperty("ner.model", "/path/to/my_model-1.ser.gz);
```

There is more exhaustive documentation here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/cmdline.html

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html

Comment: Thank You for answering, sir. But, this is what i did:
1. unzip the stanford-ner.jar.
2. place my own model in the unzip file, named "myModel".
3. Then build it again as a jar file.
The jar file and its default model is actually working in the command line but when I execute the jar file, still i have to click the classifier tab and load the model.